# VMware Fusion can't find Bootcamp on second hard drive

Tags: osx-lion, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

I have Win7 x64 installed on a SSD in my 2011 15" MacBook Pro. Lion and my Windows data (documents, profiles, etc) are stored on the conventional hard drive that came with the machine. (I removed the optical drive and replaced it with a caddy in which the second hard drive is now stored.)

I'm attempting to use Fusion to boot my existing Win7 installation, but Fusion can't find it. In the Fusion start screen, under Bootcamp, it says "No bootcamp partitions were detected."

I'm guessing that this is related to the way in which I created the partition. Initially, I had split the drive that came with the machine in half (one partition for OSX, one for Win7). When I installed the SSD, I installed Win7 on it and moved the profiles to the old NTFS partition. OSX still boots from the old drive.

Windows and Lion both boot correctly, and the Bootcamp utilities work correctly under Windows.

The only issue I have is that Fusion can't find the existing partition.

And, before anyone says it, I can't just install Win7 into a VM, or migrate the existing partition. I do quite a bit of DirectX 10 & 11 development which won't work under a VM, and I don't want to maintain two different Windows installations just to be able to use OSX.

Suggestions?

In case it matters: I can see both Windows partitions (SSD and the data partition on the original drive) from OSX, and I can see the OSX partition from Windows.